# Counterexample for functional sequence $\{f_n\}$ that converges uniformly on $E=[0;A]$ but not on $E=[0;+\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

Let functional sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $E=[0;A]$ $\forall A>0$. Does it implies this $[f_n]$ converges uniformly on $E=[0;+\infty)$?
My attempt: $$f_n(x)=\arctan nx$$

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
   -\frac{\pi}{2} &\text{x<0}\\
    0 &\text{x=0} \\
    \frac{\pi}{2} &\text{x>0}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Hence $f(x)=\arctan x \cdot \operatorname{sign}  x$ $\Rightarrow$ if we take $x=\frac{1}{n} $ then $\sup r_n= \sup |\arctan 1 - \arctan\frac{1}{n}|$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sup r_n=\frac{\pi}{4}\not = 0$ hence $f_n(x)$ doesn't converge uniformly to $f(x)$. Am I right? Is there simpler counterexamples?

Comment: $x/n {}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
Then
$$
f_n(x)\to \mathrm{e}^x,
$$
uniformly is EVERY closed interval, while it does not converge uniformly in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: so simple idea! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another counterexample:
$$f_n(x)=\min\{|x-n|,1\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f_n = 1_{[n, n+1]}\mbox{}\mbox{}$$

Answer (score 0):

$f_n(x)=x/n$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty]$ but it is so on $[0,a]$ for any $a\in (0,\infty)$.